# Web app in JQuery 1.11 failling on IE 9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

I have developed a web application with JQuery 1.11.2 and JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 in Java Server Pages. It was successfully deployed on Google App Engine.

The web app is about to go live for our customers to use. The development has been all on IE 10, Firefox and Google Chrome. The deployed web app has already been successfully tested on those web browsers. We assumed that our customers were with the same OS and IE versions as us. However, they advised that they used IE 9 and found a few issues on the front end while initially testing the web app on their IE 9.

I initially thought it was just the IE9 Compatibility View issue. As I am with IE 10 I had to go back home and test the app with one of my old computers that is with IE 9. The front end issues were cleared when I changed to IE 9 Compatibility View, but I was unable to make JQuery AJAX calls! The page styling seems fine and JQuery Mobile controls seem to work well except for "Popup" widget.

As the web app heavily relies on JQuery AJAX to submit user data to the server. I am afraid I would have to re-engine my code but I am feeling I have nowhere to go. IE is giving me a ton of trouble.

My question is which version of JQuery plus JQuery Mobile works best with IE 9 as far as AJAX is concerned. Any other suggestions as to my circumstance. Thanks!

Comment: As long as you are not using version > 2.0 it should not be a problem

Comment: I initially figured out the problem was to do with IE Options -> Security Settings. All ActiveX control related options must be checked in Custom settings of Security. Then all Ajax calls were successful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jQuery migrate plugin which will let you determine exactly what versions will work for you. [Taken from jquery download page] you can see under the migration area in section B that it tells how to diagnose these compatibility issues.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Used in conjunction with the console for NET and DOM in -> https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite and jqueryui themeroller for easy switching between versions, I was able to debug things like this in the past.

Have you any useful errors or management console barf?

Comment: The problem is very random. When I checked all the ActiveX related options by enabling them in IE9 Options -> Security Settings -> Custom Settings, all Ajax calls worked successfully.

Comment: You must have some **some** form of error message? If you are not trapping errors then I suggest you start there.

Answer (score -1):

Did you load jquery separatley for each browser?

```
<!--[if IE]><script src="path/to/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<![if !IE]><script src="path/to/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script><![endif]>
```

It works fine for me like this in ie8